# Can NOT add target attribute to an anchor

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to convert text URL to a clickable html link, everything goes fine but i can not add an attribute(target). I don't get any errors. 
Here's the code:

```
 let text= 'https://www.google.com';
 let exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
 let text1=text.replace(exp, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
 let exp2 =/(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
 let message = text1.replace(exp2, '$1<a target="_blank" href="http://$2">$2</a>');
```

Output: `<a href="https://www.google.com">https://www.google.com</a>`

Comment: What's the *desired* output?

Comment: `<a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com">https://www.google.com</a>`

Comment: Why not just add `target="_blank"` to your first replacement? Why a second pass?

Comment: let text1=text.replace(exp, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); should have target attribute            let text1=text.replace(exp, "<a target="_blank" href='$1'>$1</a>");

Comment: tried but doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for two passes. Just include the target in your initial replacement:

```js
let text= 'https://www.google.com';
let exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
let text1=text.replace(exp, '<a target="_blank" href="$1">$1</a>');
// -------------------------^---^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------^--^-------^
console.log(text1);
```

Since you seemed to want double quotes around `_blank` (it's not necessary), I changed the quotes around your replacement string to `'` (and used `"` around `href`).